# Cakephp Migrations.migration run all get Error: Database connection "Postgres" is missing, or could not be created

Tags: postgresql, cakephp

Someone please help me,

I'm new in postgresgl. Im developing application with Cakephp 2.5.1 with Migrations Plugin to run sql query under Ubuntu console.

If I try to create simple script for testing purpose, like this:

http://pastebin.com/dYv48VQc

It's work!

But I don't know what happend when I try to run Migrations.migration run all under Ubuntu console, I get some error like this:

http://pastebin.com/tBTr8FgP

And here is my Config/database.php file content, I used same user, pass, host, port and db name:

http://pastebin.com/3BzuQxmr

I have check from ubuntu console, and the PDO for pgsql has been enabled

http://pastebin.com/9aCL5ys8

Please help me, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved. I make some fresh installation of ubuntu and all service. Such as Apache, php, mysql, postgres. Then All Works!

Thanks.